# Xamarin.Android - list or array does not show values

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

While debugging list or array does not show values, only its size.

This error appears after the latest visual studio updates.

Please, has anyone ever faced this problem?

[image: example error]

For example, i created a new project xamarin and added the following code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<int> values = new List<int>();

        values.Add(1);
        values.Add(2);
        values.Add(3);

        int test = values[1];
    }
```

When placing the mouse on the values ​​list(in this line: int test = values) does not display the contents of it during debugging, I only see the amount of elements

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bug of latest visual studio 15.8.1. This has already been filed to Visual Studio developer community. Fixed but release is pending

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311540/debugger-tooltip-does-not-expand-in-xamarinios-deb.html?childToView=330904#comment-330904

The alternate way is to watch the values is

- Right click on objects--Go to Quick watch

Like below screenshot showing

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to you and others for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you click the small arrow on the left side, a drop down with the array contents will appear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Even when clicking as it was already known by me does not show the values.